# Lambda returns byte array in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I am new to java, and I faced with lambda that returns byte array.

```
@Test
@Parameters
public void shouldThrowsExceptionWhenInvalidInput(Supplier<? extends AlphabeticDatatype> supplier) {
    catchException(supplier).get();

    assertThat(caughtException())
            .isExactlyInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class)
            .hasMessageStartingWith("i18n|ex.domain.datatype.alphabetic.length");
}

private Object[] parametersForShouldThrowsExceptionWhenInvalidInput() {
    return $(
            $((Supplier<AlphabeticDatatype>) () -> new StringDatatype("ASCII", true, 63).toBytes("")),
            $((Supplier<AlphabeticDatatype>) () -> new StringDatatype("UTF-8", true, 24))
    );
}
```

Am writing unit-test fro my custom datatype. I just need to invoke toBytes() to check exception.
But this lambda:

```
(Supplier<AlphabeticDatatype>) () -> new StringDatatype("ASCII", true, 63).toBytes("")
```

saying that "***Incompatible return type byte[] in lambda expression***"

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply because:

```
() -> new StringDatatype("ASCII", true, 63).toBytes("")
```

This is of type `Supplier<byte[]>` where as you typecast it to `(Supplier<AlphabeticDatatype>)`.

Typecasting is wrong. If you are doing it, then you are pretending stuff. And it can go terribly wrong.